# JWT and implementations

Tags: architecture, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am looking at securing an API and was recommended JWT based approach although after reading online and following several tutorials I am more confused than I was before.  So here is what I gather: JWT is a standard and there are several implementations...so am I right that I have to pick an implementation to use for my API?

If so are there are out of the box implementations I can use which are industry recommended to avoid reinventing the wheel?  As a .net developer I would more likely use `Asp.Net Identity` which can issue and validate JWT I believe (correct me if I am wrong).  Is that the best approach? Seems fairly heavy handed though...what about any open source projects?

I don't really want to roll my own implementation...looking for any advice on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

JWT is just a standard [RFC 75 19](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) with many implementations.

For a list of implementations check out https://jwt.io/ (you can filter by language), there are three .net implementations so you don't need to (and shouldn't) roll your own.

#### Introduction to Signed JWT (JWS)

A signed JWT includes a Base64 Url Safe encoded signature as the third component. The algorithm used to generate the signature is indicated in the header.

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
.eyJzdWIiOiJKb2huIERvZSIsImFkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJpYXQiOjE0NzAzNTM5OTQsImV4cCI6MTQ3MDM1NzYyNywianRpIjoiNmU0MDRiYTgtZjg4NS00ZDVmLWJmYTItZTNmNWEwODM4MGE0In0
.7CfBdVP4uKsb0cogYepCvMLm8rcpjBYW1XZzA-a5e44
```

### Header

```js
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
```

This JWT was signed with the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm, hence `alg: HS256`.

### Payload

```js
{
  "sub": "John Doe",
  "admin": true,
  "iat": 1470353994,
  "exp": 1470357627,
  "jti": "6e404ba8-f885-4d5f-bfa2-e3f5a08380a4"
}
```

This JWT can be verified with the UTF-8 secret `notsosecret`.

Excerpted from [Getting started with jwt - Signed JWT (JWS)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006215845/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jwt/5213/getting-started-with-jwt/18559/signed-jwt-jws#t=201710062158457098024). The original author was [Nate Barbettini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3191599/nate-barbettini). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/18559). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 5213 and example ID: 18559.